# Regex that replace all sourcecode for files in some folder

Tags: regex

I want to replace all sourcecode(and text, everything) in files in some folders. I use Dreamweaver and Notepad ++
I try with this:

```
Find: ([\s\S]*?)

Replace: Replace everything with this.
```

Now, the problem is ([\s\S]*?) is not matching "everything" in the every page.I need some help, I bad in using regex.

.*  is not working. Try yourself it won't mark the whole page....

Comment: The regular exoression for "everything" is `.*` (any character, zero or more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `?`. It is non-greedy matcher.

So use this regex:

```
[\s\S]*
```

replace with any string.

Comment: You are right. Regards and thank you. You have been very helpful.

Comment: glad to have helped ;)